# Choosing the right capacitors for multiple sub-loads in the system when the main power source is unreliable

Tags: capacitor-charging

[image]

Hello there,

I'm working on a system that has unreliable power source like solar cell (that why I put a switch in the schematic to indicates that).The general idea of the system is breaking out the total loads to multi-sub loads where each sub-load has its own capacitor to extend its working time in case the main power source was insufficient for sometime. I'm using a voltage divider to prioritize the charge  of the sub-loads capacitors as well as using a comparator with reference based on the needs of my system applications. Also, I have an extra capacitor C4 to work as a backup when the power source is off. This extra capacitor has the lower priority among all sub-loads.

My question is how do I choose the sizes of the capacitors for each sub-loads based on the load itself and the size of  the backup capacitor? Initially I'm using a largest capacitor for backup. For the sub-load I use small capacitor for small sub-load and large one for the large sub-load. This decision is not reasonable and really want to learn how do I make this decision to be close to optimal based on engineering formulas/theories.

I'm not an engineer but have some basic background. I knew there is a voltage drop across the diode (I'm using Schottky diodes in my system) as well as the resistors I used in the voltage devisors. Also, I'm aware that large capacitors have large leakage where I tried to avoid by using a capacitor as small as possible.

I would appreciate any explanation or referring to a source that can help me to understand how to choose the capacitor size based on a given load as well as a backup capacitor. Please I'm still learning and a predicate a simple explanation or simple resources that explain a similar issue for a non-engineer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what supplies Vin?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to build here. It seems that you are trying to use op-amps to charge capacitors through rather high resistor values to **power a load**. How much current are you hoping to draw from each capacitor? With a 10k source impedance you'll get a maximum of 1 mA if the op-amp output is 10 V and the capacitor voltage will collapse to 0 V.

Comment: You need to know how much current (I) the load draws, how long you need to run it for (t), and the change in supply voltage (dV) it can tolerate, e.g. if it runs from 3.3V down to 3.0V, dV = 3.3-3 = 0.3V. I * T gives you the charge, Q you need to store. And C = Q/dV gives you the capacitor value.

Comment: @user_1818839 Vin is supplied from the power source.

Comment: @Transistor My system is very complicated. So, Tried to simplify it by just putting sub-loads.

Comment: @user_1818839 this is very helpful answer to reasonably choose the capacitor size for all sub-loads. How do I decide how big my backup capacitor should be to be optimal for supporting other sub-load capacitors? I knew that some current and voltage will get lost through diodes and resistors, but choosing very large capacitor my take very long time to charge and might not be ready when it needed (when power source provide insufficient amount).

Comment: @Aalsubhi The voltage change on a capacitor, when it is supplying current (to one, two, or fifteen loads, it doesn't matter, you just need to estimate the worst case *total*), is \$\Delta V = \Delta t\cdot \frac{I}{C}\$. Assuming \$I\$ (worst case total) and \$C\$ are constants, of course. So you can size the capacitor based upon: \$C=I\cdot\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta V}\$, where \$\Delta V\$ is the largest allowable droop you want to accept and \$\Delta t\$ is the worst case time period you may have to suffer through. Longer times mean a bigger capacitor. Less droop means a bigger capacitor. Etc.

Comment: "*So, Tried to simplify it by just putting sub-loads.*" What are these loads? What is their operating voltage? What current do they require?

Comment: Thanks @jonk. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Same way. Decide what (current,time,dV) the backup capacitor needs to deliver and calculate C. At some point you are probably going to realise why everybody else uses batteries for anything more than trivial amounts of power...